# Anyone knows how to use scispaCy model in rasa for bio-medical?

Tags: python, nlp, rasa-nlu, rasa, rasa-core

**Anyone knows how to use scispaCy model in rasa for bio-medical?**
i am trying to build a chatbot with rasa and anyone suggest me nlp model for healthcare chatbot

Answer (score 0):

At the time of writing, spaCy 2.3 is the most recent version of spaCy and for that version, there's a blogpost [written here](https://blog.rasa.com/custom-spacy-components/) that describes how to convert a custom spaCy pipeline for use in Rasa.

The main steps include saving a model pipeline to disk.

```py
nlp.meta["name"] = "proglang"
nlp.to_disk(nlp.meta["name"])
```

And then installing this model as a python package.

```py
> python -m spacy package proglang . --force
> cd en_proglang-2.2.5 # this created name depends on the spaCy version
> python setup.py sdist 
> python -m pip install en_proglang-2.2.5/dist/en_proglang-2.2.5.tar.gz
```

Once all of this is done you can refer to this model from Rasa's `config.yml` file.

```yaml
pipeline:
- name: SpacyNLP
  model: "en_proglang"
- name: SpacyTokenizer
- name: SpacyEntityExtractor
- name: SpacyFeaturizer
  pooling: mean
- name: CountVectorsFeaturizer
  analyzer: char_wb
  min_ngram: 1
  max_ngram: 4
- name: DIETClassifier
  epochs: 100
```

The blog post explains it in more detail though. Definitely give that a full read.

A few points on this approach though.

- With the advent of spaCy 3.0 some of these steps might change. The blogpost is likely to receive an update once Rasa upgrades to this new spaCy version.
- This guide works for general spaCy models but I'm not familiar with `sci-spaCy` and I, therefore, do not know if there are some internal tricks that make it different than a normal spaCy pipeline. There are wrappers like [stanza spaCy](https://github.com/explosion/spacy-stanza) for example that do not work via this approach.
- If you find that this approach does not work, you might want to start a github issue on [the rasa-nlu-examples project](https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa-nlu-examples). It's a contrib-like module for Rasa components and there might be an interest in adding such features.

Comment: Okay thank you so much....but does spacy has an entity for drug names....since I want to build a healthcare chatbot and issue related to healthcare is spacy has some futures or pre embedded words or examples in medical sector?

Comment: There can be public spaCy models that have those entities; aye. The simple starter kit of spaCy does not though.